# What keyword to use in the class declaration if you do not want to create an instance of the class?

Tags: c#

Here is the question I received in a recent technical test:

> Which of the following keywords is used in a class declaration if you do NOT want to create instances of the class?

- null
- void
- private
- empty

Also, what is the relevancy of this in a real world situation? (i.e. is it used a lot)  (and no static was not an option, which I would have expected to see).

Comment: I don't see how any of those keywords applies.  Of those four, I've only ever seen `private` used in a class declaration, and that doesn't do what the question is asking.

Comment: You should be happy that you don't get to work in such a crappy company

Comment: You simply declare all of type's constructors as `private`, and do not provide any additional API to create it's insances (e.g. factory method).

Comment: @Yuriy: Even still, that keyword alone doesn't *prevent* instances from being created.  Perhaps instances can only be created within the class itself, but they're still instances.  All things considered, it's a broken interview question.

Comment: Yeah don't feel bad that it threw you, I think Sean's answer is correct.  They must have been talking about the constructor, because `private class` is implicit and the other options wouldn't be syntactically correct for `class`.  Must have been referring to the constructor(?)

Comment: Depending on who was asking the question they may have just been checking to see if you were aware of various methods for creating a class. My guess is they didn't think through the answers too thoroughly.

Comment: I find it laughable that a technical C# test when asked to a C# community here, was flagged as "closed as unclear what you're asking"

Answer (score 9):

> Which of the following keywords is used in a class declaration if you
>   do NOT want to create instances of the class?
>
> A) null B) void C) private D) empty

None.

`null` and `void` aren't valid keywords in a class declaration, `empty` isn't a keyword at all and `private` doesn't prevent one from creating an instance.

Trick question?

**Edit**

To answer your second question, classes that cannot be instanciated are commonly used to hold related utility methods that do not require any kind of state to be saved after being called or [Extension Methods](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us//library/bb383977.aspx) (in the case of extension methods the class MUST be declared static).

Comment: If this was a multiple choice question, we can assume the question's writer wanted an answer. From that, I'd assume the answer was `private` and that the question was simply badly worded. I'd make sure to consider both possibilities.

Comment: @Magus You're most likely right. I just like being nitpicky ;)

Comment: +1 (Second?) non-constructive comment of the day - still worth noting that `private` as a class access modifier (on a non-nested class) _will_ prevent you from creating an instance -  because it won't compile. But if we're going for that kind of reasoning, all four answers are correct. :-P

Answer (score 5):

I think they were likely going for "private" as applied to the default constructor to prevent it being invoked, rather having instantiation being done via a static factory method, it at all.

Comment: Which of the following keywords is used in a "class declaration" not "constructor declaration"

Comment: "Which of the following keywords is used in a **class declaration**", it is very misleading

Comment: Should be noted that even `private` is not a good answer considering it's about a class declaration.

Comment: @LucasAbilidebob Assuming this was a trick question (which is also what "alsed42" indicated). This is as good an answer as any

Comment: @drew_w No. Nothing option is good.

Comment: Technically, a constructor declaration _is part_ of the class declaration. "A class-declaration consists of an optional set of attributes (§17), followed by an [... cut for brevity ...] , followed by an optional set of type-parameter-constraints-clauses (§10.1.5), __followed by a class-body (§10.1.6)__, optionally followed by a semicolon." Even if that doesn't make the answer "private" correct. ;-)

Comment: @LucasAbilidebob: If it was a trick question, then yes, the correct answer is "none of the above; static", but if it was simply a badly written question, this answer is correct. I'd suggest being aware of both possibilities. Assuming the wrong one would be a bigger mistake.

Comment: I'll freely allow that it's a bad question. And I probably ought to have explained my answer further, but I'll admit that I dashed off the answer before moving on to something else. I do think it's likely what the interviewer was looking for. If it's a case where you can talk to the interviewer about your answers, that's more or less how you'd justify your answer right before you point out that it's a partially correct answer, at best. Politely, of course. :)

Answer (score 0):

I'd rather use instatiation instead of declaration. In this case I'd choose null that is

```
MyClass mc=null;
```

Comment: null i what I ended up choosing..  And they marked it as wrong.  :(

Comment: Then as mentioned above the question is not correctly posed